# How to change Windows admin password from guest user

Tags: windows-xp

How to gain access of admin account of Windows, I activated a guest user and I want to change the admin password from the command line. When I type:

```
net user administrator password
```

the response is

```
System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied
```

**I am using winxp pro sp2**

I am running this command from cdm.exe and I am running this command from guest user.
I actually want to change my admin password from guest user.

Comment: Are you running this from an elevated prompt command?

Comment: i am running this command from cmd, and i am running this command from guest user.

Comment: `cmd.exe` does not grant special privileges.

Comment: There's this concept of *security* ... allowing a guest user to change the admin password... well... that would be bad.  Very Very Bad.  Try booting into Safe Mode.

Comment: if administrator user is password protected than?

Answer (score 5):

Guest users cannot change the administrator password.

Comment: so how can i change it i wan't yo change my 32bit server password i forgot it and only guest and one limited account is enable only .

Comment: You can't change it without [modifying the SAM registry hive](http://home.eunet.no/~pnordahl/ntpasswd/)

Comment: this is more technically correct

Answer (score 3):

At the login screen, press

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> **twice**

Now in the box that appears, type the username as Administrator and leave the password empty and log in. Now change your password.

Comment: if the admin account is password protected and i forgot then...

Comment: @Lynch is John Smith your another account ?

Comment: no i asked you if admin is protected how to do then

Comment: @Lynch http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/01/kon-boot-getting-into-a-clients-computer-without-using-a-portal-gun/

Comment: @JohnSmiith Good to know

Comment: HackToHell JiGar kya hal ha!!

Comment: @Lynch Je ne suis pas en hindi

Comment: HackToHell , its urdu bro

Comment: a nice guess....
administrator passwords for XP are quite often left blank..

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change password via your guest user.

- Boot your PC from Safe Mode by pressing F8 when PC stars.
- Login the accessible account with administrator privileges.
- Start - Local Users and Groups – lusrmgr.msc in the Search box - ENTER.
- Local Users and Groups - choose Users.
- Right click the account needed to reset password, and then select Set Password.
- Input and confirm the new password.

Answer (score -1):

As it's the guest account that is logged in your powers to change settings on the system are minimal if nothing. Log out and log in as a user that has the authority as set up in the user accounts in order to perform this. If you are still stuck see if you can get your hands on the Hirens Boot Disk, as this has a useful function that allows you to edit any users password on that machine etc.